# Django won't use postgres schema properly

Tags: python, django, postgresql, schema

I have a problem with using schema while running tests with django.
All tables in my postgres database are in schema, let's name it 'schema'.
In my **settings.py** i added:

```
    'OPTIONS': {
        'options': '-c search_path=schema',
        'connect_timeout': 5,
    },
```

to tell django to use 'schema' schema. 
All production code is working perfectly.

Problem is:
When i added DB testing and run

```
python manage.py test
```

it resulted with

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in

I tried to remove schema-line from **settings.py** and add 'schema.' at the beginning of every db_table name in **models.py**.
It worked for tests, but now when i run my production code, it ends up with:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "schema.table" does not exist

How can i tell **manage.py** to create db with schema, so i don't have to modify **models.py** or **settings.py**?
Or how can i properly add usage of my schema in **models.py** ?